# Phonegap CLI upgrade

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli

Good day.

Please I am kinda new to cordova and phonegap. I built a mobile app using phonegap sometime ago. Now I noticed that I still see the "we recommend you upgrade to phonegap 5.2.0-cli" message even after editing my config.xml file.

Can anyone advise on steps that should be taken in order to effect this upgrade so that I can stop seeing this message every time I build my app into an apk file?  I have checked solutions all over the internet and all I see is that I should add

```
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
```

to my code.

I have done this but still no difference. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check whether your phonegap version is upgraded to 5.2.0 by typing "phonegap -v" in your command prompt

Comment: I see that it is 6.0.4 @Gandhi